# Virtuoso SPARQL query unable to compare float constants

Tags: sparql, virtuoso

I have a local copy of DBpedia 2014 loaded onto Virtuoso 7.1. I run the following query:

```
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

SELECT ?o, datatype(?o)
WHERE {
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Caesar_Creek_State_Park> <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#long> ?o .
}
```

obtaining the following result:

```
o           callret-1
-84.0653    http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float
-84.0139    http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float
```

I now execute the (seemingly true) query:

```
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

ASK
WHERE {
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Caesar_Creek_State_Park> <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#long> "-84.0139"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float> .
}
```

where the return value is `false`!

Next I try ensuring the `float` value with a `FILTER`:

```
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

SELECT ?o
WHERE {
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Caesar_Creek_State_Park> <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#long> ?o .
  FILTER ( datatype(?o) = xsd:float )
}
```

This returns:

```
o
-84.0653
-84.0139
```

Which is good. Next, I try to sneak in an extra triple pattern into the previous query:

```
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

SELECT ?o
WHERE {
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Caesar_Creek_State_Park> <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#long> ?o .
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Caesar_Creek_State_Park> <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#long> "-84.0139"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float> .
  FILTER ( datatype(?o) = <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float> )
}
```

which returns empty!

Sadly, the online endpoint at [lod.openlinksw.com/sparql](http://lod.openlinksw.com/sparql) doesn't have latitudes and longitudes loaded, so I wasn't able to replicate the problem for you to see first-hand.

Any suggetions? My main question is: how can I place a literal `float` in a triple pattern of a query in order to obtain a match?

Comment: Instead of `SELECT ?o, datatype(?o)`, what do you get if you `SELECT str(?o), datatype(?o)`?  It may be that the client is printing a float that it read from the RDF literal, which might not end up being exactly the lexical form of the RDF literal.

Comment: Note that the datasets at http://lod.openlinksw.com/sparql and http://dbpedia.org/sparql were extracted some time ago. More actively updated data -- which does include the lat/long values -- can be found at http://dbpedia-live.openlinksw.com/sparql and http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that Virtuoso is rounding or truncating the value when it's printing the value.  As a very simple example that you can run on the public DBpedia endpoint (which runs Virtuoso):

```sql
select ?x, (str(?x) as ?sx) {
  values ?x { 
    "1.11111"^^xsd:float
    "1.11115"^^xsd:float
    "1.11119"^^xsd:float
  }
}
```

[SPARQL Results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20%3Fx%2C%20%28str%28%3Fx%29%20as%20%3Fsx%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20values%20%3Fx%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%221.11111%22%5E%5Exsd%3Afloat%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%221.11115%22%5E%5Exsd%3Afloat%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%221.11119%22%5E%5Exsd%3Afloat%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)

```
x        sx
--------------------------
1.11111  1.111109972000122
1.11115  1.111150026321411
1.11119  1.111189961433411
```

If you want to compare exact values, you'll probably want to extract those string forms and look for them explicitly.

And of course, there's the obligatory link to [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: You're absolutely right. Somehow the formatting `"81.5"^^<html...float>` gave me the very wrong impression that I was dealing with a stored string.

Comment: @gdiazc Well, in a sense, you *are* dealing with a stored string.  A (datatyped) RDF literal is a pair of a lexical form (a string) and a datatype URI.  While they might not all be semantically legal, you could pair any string with any datatype URI, and have an RDF literal.  The [spec says](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#matchArbDT) that you're supposed to be able to match just by putting a specific lexical form and datatype literal.  I *think* that might mean that what Virtuoso is doing here isn't quite legal, since it's returning a different lexical form than the one that I typed in.